# How to load a binary file from the server filesystem into Vite/Vue3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I would like to load (and process) data that is stored in a binary file on the server.

*Vue.app*

```
<script setup>
import * as fs from 'fs'
const content = fs.readFile('./filename')
</script>

<template>
</template>

<style>
</style>
```

... results in:

```
Uncaught TypeError: fs.readFile is not a function
```

What is the way?